# Running subscribeOn action in the same thread as Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, scheduling

I need to run `subscribeOn` action in the same thread as `Observable`. I found a solution but it seems it's not the best. Basically I use the same `scheduler` for initial `observable` and `observable` which `doOnSubscribe` returns:

```
Scheduler singleThreadScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

Observable<Object> obs = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

    System.out.println("onNext at: " + Thread.currentThread());

    subscriber.onNext(new Object());
    subscriber.onCompleted();

}).subscribeOn(singleThreadScheduler).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

obs = obs.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("doOnSubscribe at: " + Thread.currentThread())).subscribeOn(singleThreadScheduler);

obs.subscribe(o -> {
    System.out.println("result at: " + Thread.currentThread());
});
```

Log:

```
doOnSubscribe at: Thread[pool-1-thread-1] //runs on the same thread
onNext at: Thread[pool-1-thread-1]        //runs on the same thread
result at: Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1]
```

Is there any better or maybe more standard way to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is there thread-local information outside the observable chain? Also, there's `Scheduler.immediate()`

Comment: This is the only way you can get back to the same thread in 1.x. The standard schedulers hand out worker threads and there is no guarantee you get the same when you apply the schedulers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As akarnokd noted the solution which I mention in the question is only one.